# execute api function on button click using Django urls - Django/Python

Tags: python, django, api, url

As it stands I have my site set up and there is a search bar and search button which I wish to execute my api function located in my api.py file. The api.py file looks like so:

```
import urllib2
import json

locu_api = '****'

def loc_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    api_key = locu_api
    url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
    locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')
    final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=restaurant"
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)

    for item in data['objects']:
        print item['name']
        print item['phone']
```

I have added into my urls.py like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = patterns(
"",
url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="home"),
url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),
url(r"^api/", 'loc_search', name="search"),
)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Am i calling it right in my urls? my api file is in my main folder along with my urls.py? that being said I have then called it within my form like so:

```
          <form action="{% url "search" %}">
<div class="input-group">
<input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="addressSearch">Search</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

But when I search nothing happens. as far as im aware i believe i have set it up correctly but I am obviously mistaken, im fairly new to django so any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Well, your `loc_search` function doesn't seem to be returning anything, so you must be getting an exception from Django.

Comment: does it not return the name and phone numbers? it does when i tested it jsut in python shell

Comment: No, it prints them to the console, it doesn't return them. Again, Django will be showing you an error message because it is obligatory to return a response from a view. You should read that error.

Comment: It prints them, which is very different than returning values (and has little meaning in a Django view).

Comment: I see, point taken, so whats an easy way to test this like to print directly into a text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem your api call

i strongly advice you to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) otherwise you will do stuff like `locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')` which urlencodes spaces but what about all the other stuff like öäü + * ? etc. ?

```
import requests

api_params = {'api_key':locu_api, 'locality': locality, 'category':'restaurant'}
apicall = requests.get(api_url, params=api_params)
json_respons = apicall.json()
```

Your second problem is (Daniel Roseman mentioned it) that this is a view (which should be in the views.py) and has to return a http response. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/)

copypasta

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    # this will return a html as a http response
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

before asking basics you should do the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: Thanks alot guys I will try this as soon as I get home and let you know